# Correct Connected (Across Staves) Arpeggio Collission

Tags: notation, sheet-music, lilypond

In context, the collision looks like this:

[image: Collision]

Here's a minimum example that appears to reproduce the problem:

```
\version "2.22.1"

rh=\relative c'' {\key des \major
    <g g'>4.( <e e'>8 <f f'>4) <ges aes c ges'>\arpeggio \ff |
}

lh=\relative c {\clef "bass" \key des \major
    << {
        e,16( g bes c) e,( g bes c) f,( a c f,) <aes c>4\arpeggio |
    } \\ {
        e4 e f ees\arpeggio |
    }>>
}

\score
{
    <<
        \new PianoStaff \with {connectArpeggios = ##t} <<
            \new Staff = "up" \rh
            \new Staff = "down" \lh
        >>
    >>
}
```

which yields:

[image: Minimum Example]

How do I create space to the left of the arpeggio object? I've tried `\override`ing properties, but none of them have ANY effect on the arpeggio object at all. Adding `\override Arpeggio.direction = #UP` before the music in `rh` doesn't produce any compilation errors, but also doesn't change the arpeggio object. Same with `\override Arpeggio.padding = #3`. `\override Arpeggio.positions = #( 3 . 5 )` fails with compile error "Wrong number of arguments to 3" (how many arguments does 3 expect?).

Obviously I'm clueless about Lilypond syntax (still). How do I fix the arpeggio collision? Also, please provide general comments on how to interact with lilypond objects.

Answer (score 2):

The reason the `\override`s don't work is because you failed to place them on every instance of the `\arpeggio` object. When using `connectArpeggios` event, it is necessary to apply the override to ALL the `\arpeggio` statements in the score:

```
\version "2.22.1"

rh=\relative c'' {\key des \major
\override Arpeggio.padding = #3
    <g g'>4.( <e e'>8 <f f'>4) \override Arpeggio.padding = #3 <ges aes c ges'>\arpeggio \ff |
}

lh=\relative c {\clef "bass" \key des \major
    << {
        e,16( g bes c) e,( g bes c) f,( a c f,) \override Arpeggio.padding = #3 <aes c>4\arpeggio |
    } \\ {
        e4 e f \override Arpeggio.padding = #3 ees\arpeggio |
    }>>
}

\score
{
    <<
        \new PianoStaff \with {connectArpeggios = ##t} <<
            \new Staff = "up" \rh
            \new Staff = "down" \lh
        >>
    >>
}
```

yields:

[image: Corrected Collision]